# Trouble running Java application implementing Stanford POS tagger as a .jar, runs fine in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to implement Stanford's POS tagger in a Java application using the following lines of code:

```
             MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
             String taggedString = tagger.tagString(string);
```

It works fine when running the project in NetBeans, but the executable .jar compiled in NetBeans will not run the tagger.  I am fairly new to Java and to programming in general, and I haven't figured out how to log whatever error/exception is occurring in the GUI console of the application, and no error/exception occurs when running the project in NetBeans.

A couple things occurred to me that could be happening.  The Stanford NLP group says:

"The system requires Java 1.8+ to be installed. Depending on whether you're running 32 or 64 bit Java and the complexity of the tagger model, you'll need somewhere between 60 and 200 MB of memory to run a trained tagger (i.e., you may need to give java an option like java -mx200m). Plenty of memory is needed to train a tagger. It again depends on the complexity of the model but at least 1GB is usually needed, often more."  http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml

In the shortcut that I use to run the application, I specified the path of a javaw.exe that is version 1.8+, and I also tried replacing the latest release of the tagger with the August 2014 release, pre-Java 8 upgrade, and neither solved the problem.

As for the memory issue, I went to my Java control panel and entered "-Xms1024m" as a runtime parameter for every javaw.exe on my machine, and that also did not solve the problem.

Can anybody suggest what might be making the .jar fail to run the tagger, when it works fine running the project from NetBeans?

Thanks!

Comment: We really can't do without the error messages/stack trace, and maybe some additional code will be needed. For the error log, if you cannot select, copy and paste it, how about taking a screenshot and linking to it from your question?

Comment: [`MaxentTagger(String modelFile)`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger.html#MaxentTagger-java.lang.String-) - Constructor for a tagger, loading a model stored in a particular file, classpath resource, or URL. It seems like the constructor allows a few different paths, which it will check each type until one is successful. Your path is assuming it is from a File on the file system, which won't work once it's jarred. So for it work in the jar, try using a classpath path (e.g. `"/taggers/file.tagger"`) and make `taggers` a package in the src

Comment: There is no error log - the application just hangs up / freezes.  I don't think MaxentTagger throws any exceptions.  Is there a way to catch and log an error/exception that would be associated with trying to run an application that requires Java 1.8+ on Java 1.7, if that happens to be the issue?  Or that the platform is not allocating enough memory if that happens to be the issue?

Comment: You can implement logging functionality to write to a text file, or use a JOptionPane MessageDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

peeskillet that worked, thanks (great name by the way)! Specifically, in the projects tab I right-clicked "Source Packages" > "New" > "Java Package," called the new package "taggers," and moved the .tagger files into the "taggers" directory under the "src" directory under the project root directory.

Comment: I assume the root cause was that `RuntimeIOException` was being thrown trying to load the model, and that your code doesn't catch and log Exception.  There are ways other than using the classpath to bundle assets with your application, but it isn't really until JavaFX that Oracle [makes a recommendation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#A1308687) on how to do this in a platform-agnostic manner.